# Spring Data JPA limiting query results throws NumberFormatException

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity for which I would like to use a `JpaRepository`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MESSAGE")
public class MessageEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "TRACE_ID", nullable = false)
    private String traceId;
    @Column(name = "REGISTRATION", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime registration;
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting) I should be able to retrieve the first result by defining the method name as follows:

```
public interface MessageJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<MessageEntity, Long> {
    MessageEntity getFirstByOrderByRegistrationDesc();
}
```

... and this works.

However, when I add a condition to filter on a parameter, a `NumberFormatException` is thrown.

```
public interface MessageJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<MessageEntity, Long> {
    // (OrderBy removed for simplicity)
    MessageEntity getFirstByTraceId(String traceId);
    MessageEntity getFirst1ByTraceId(String traceId);
}
```

When I call this method with `messageJpaRepository.getFirstByTraceId("trace.id")`, the following is printed:

```
select TOP ?
  message0_.ID as ID1_0_,
  message0_.TRACE_ID as TRACE_ID2_0_,
  message0_.REGISTRATION_TIMESTAMP as REGISTRA3_0_
from Message message0_
where message0_.TRACE_ID = ?
```

> binding parameter [1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting) as [VARCHAR] - [trace.id]
>
> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error converting "trace.id"; SQL statement:
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "trace.id"

Changing the result type to List does not work either.

**How can I combine a limit with a condition?**

**Note:** The problem I'm facing is that Hibernate expects 2 parameters, a limit and a condition. But the condition is interpreted as the limit.

Comment: Your `trace.id` will be escaped a `varchar`, try declaring the parameter as a `Long` in your repository .

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "trace.id"

this means you are trying to parse the actual `String "trace.id"` to a number, not a value you got from a column named "trace.id". 
You'll need to re-work your code, and check where you set the "trace.id" value. Is this a value you got from the DB, then check your DB

Comment: The "trace.id" is for my WHERE clause, but somehow it is being used for the limit, instead of the default "1"